# Does coffee cause gastrointestinal problems?

Tags: health

My sister, she got gastritis when she drinks coffee she feels poignant in the area of her stomach. So, I want to know that why do people who have gastrointestinal problems when having coffee got to have stomach ache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the article titled "[Coffee and gastrointestinal function: facts and fiction. A review.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10499460)", it is stated that it has pharmacological effects and coffee promotes gastro-oesophageal reflux.

These discussions may be related:

- [What constituant in coffee has a laxative effect?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/147/what-constituant-in-coffee-has-a-laxative-effect)
- [Why is coffee a laxative?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1655/why-is-coffee-a-laxative)

Comment: Thank you so much for your kindness giving me the source of information.

Comment: @M.molika Hey, this is the aim of [Coffee SE](http://coffee.stackexchange.com)!

Comment: Lol! YES! It is.

Answer (score 1):

Caffeine is a stimulant which is the family of drugs that is used for suppressing appetite for diet pills.  It's possible that her reaction is a physiological to the stimulant, and not the chemicals in coffee, itself.

When I have too much coffee, my stomach feels off, myself.

Comment: "Too much" will obviously vary from person to person.

Comment: @brendo234 - True dat. One good-sized mug of strong coffee is pretty much my limit.

Comment: "good-sized mug" will obviously vary from person to person. ;-) LOL